# Structure members break, when accompanied with brackets

Tags: c, python-sphinx

Example:

```
.. member:: CK_UTF8CHAR model[16]
```

Gives me both the type and the name bolded and hyperlink not working.

Practically we are forced to use this cases like that:

```
.. member:: model
```

Because otherwise it would be incorrect (use it without array and with the same type).

Comment: this doesn't seem to resemble C

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: The question is how to make `.. member:: CK_UTF8CHAR model[16]` in Python Sphinx work as it should with this kind of C struct member.

Comment: It would work just fine without the [] part, but it wouldn't be right as we need an array of `CK_UTF8CHAR`, not the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this seems to be a real bug in Sphinx. I [reported](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/1539/structure-members-break-when-accompanied) that and it was confirmed. I've come up with a little workaround for now, but it's more of a crutch. Just put the following to the `layout.html` file of your Sphinx theme:

```
<script>
    $('dl.member dt').each(function() {
      $(this).find('big:first').text('[')
      $(this).find('big:last').text(']')
    });
</script>
```

Now you may use parenthesis instead of brackets in broken structures: `model(16)` becomes `model[16]` (and `label(\ )` becomes `label[]`, but only within the `.. member::` directive.

I know it is not a very elegant solution, but it is OK as a temporary fix, until the bug gets resolved.